# Can Visual VM detect which block of the code is taking most of the processing time?

Tags: java, profiler, visualvm

I am trying to find out which part of the code of a method is taking the longest time to run.

The familiar way is to using `System.nanotime` or `millisecond` but can we do the same with java profiler like Visual VM?

Comment: Can you move the "part of the code of a method" in a new method and profile/count this method instead?

Comment: @Progman yeah, actually, I did that and measure running time by the old fashion way using system.nanotime but I am wondering if I can do it with profiler tool like Visual VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Visual VM can do that. I will suggest to keep eye on the "self time" and "invocation count" of costly method(s). You will get hint where code is spending time.

Also please keep in mind that while you turn on profiler, your code will run little bit slower than usual as profiler is collecting data.

[image]